# Rough estimate of server performance

Tags: linux, performance

I have several servers, with different hardware and different operating system releases (but all Ubuntu based).

I would like to know the difference in performance between those servers, by issuing simple commands. I do not need it to be a very accurate measurement, just a rough estimate. I am specially interested in disk, memory and cpu performance.

Is there a simple way to gather this information?

Usually I would do:

```
user@server ~ » cat /proc/cpuinfo  | grep bogo
bogomips        : 4265.02
bogomips        : 4265.41
bogomips        : 4265.40
bogomips        : 4265.41

user@server ~ » cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal
MemTotal:        4043652 kB
```

But I would like a bit more info. A small performance test would be very interesting. Is there any tool for that?

For disks we have:

```
user@server ~ » sudo hdparm -t /dev/mapper/callisto-root
/dev/mapper/callisto-root:
 Timing buffered disk reads:  386 MB in  3.00 seconds = 128.59 MB/sec
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Phoronix Test Suite](http://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/). It can do many tests so it's on you to select what you need.

Answer (score 0):

For quick CPU performance testing, I would use `sysbench` (available on all unix systems) and compare with the results available here: 
http://www.blogger.com/comment.g?blogID=7143401328277522244&postID=8214188466065254085
Note that by using a CPU testing programm, you also stress test the compiler, but since all your systems have the same OS, I guess sysbench has been compiled with the same gcc.

For disk performance I would use `bonnie++` and compare with the results available here:
http://pastebin.com/XqaaT3bk
Don't use hdparm for performance testing, it does not reproduce a realistic server I/O.

I would say "memory performance" has little impact on your overall server speed.